# getting osk.exe to run from C#

Tags: c#, windows-7

I have VS2010, C# program that is setup to build as x86.  I have two PCs where they are running.  Both are Win 7 Prof, SP1, 32 bits. Both VS2010s are running at Admin level.  Within my project I try to execute the line:

```
Process.Start("c:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe");  //win 7 on-screen keyboard
```

From debug mode-run, on one system it runs fine, on the other, an exception is thrown:
    **The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.**

I have the user control setting in Win 7--User Accounts to "never notify" as suggested from other sites, that did not work.

I have tried:  (same result, fail)

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  //have tried it true also
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\osk.exe";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
```

Any ideas what needs to be changed (or do)?

Comment: What if you run the exe from outside the IDE?  Try running both as the normal user and then as administrator.

Comment: is this a Winforms app or Console app

Comment: Did you try to start osk.exe directly by explorer or from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? I altered it a bit using the System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo Class

```
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\WINDOWS\system32\";
    startInfo.FileName = "osk.exe";
    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    try
    {
        using(Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        //throw;
    }
```